# Align to objects outside your layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a new to android, and I have been trying to make an interface for an abstract game I came up with.

I have a board with 5x5 cells, and I have tiles that go in these cells.
I wanted to make animations in which the tiles fall from the top of the screen into their places in the cells, so I've been trying to align the tiles inside the cell from my topmost layout.

I know I can put the tile code in the bottom most layout, the cells themselves, but if I do that, they do not animate properly, because the elements are displayed only inside the constraints of their parent.

Here is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eeeeee"
tools:context="com.example.althis.testsequence.FullscreenActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tile1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/tile_color"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="35dp"/>

    <com.example.me.testsequence.Square_Linear_Layout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/space"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/a1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="@drawable/space">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/tile_color"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="35dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.althis.testsequence.Square_Linear_Layout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I removed most of the repeated code for legibility, but the bottom most layout is repeated five times for each row.
The button in the a1 cell is just to exemplify how I tried doing it before. The button aligns properly, but as I mentioned, it doesn't animate properly.

So, is there a smarter way to align the buttons with objects on lower layouts?

Comment: Try looking into GridLayout

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried what you suggested, the problem is that I either need to put the GridLayout inside the layout that contains my board(which creates the same problem of the animation getting cut at the top of the board layout), or I need to make my board into a bitmap and chop it into a lot of tiny pieces to make it fit into cells or a bigger layout, which would be just a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are new to android dev but your layout hierarchy is overly complicated for the problem you are trying to solve. The inner-most view of your hierarchy is 8 levels deep with several LinearLayouts. Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html first. This is very important when dealing with animations. Deeper hierarchies require exponentially more frame time for laying out the different views. If you change the size/position of a view during an animation this should preferably happen within your 16ms frame time.

Now for animating the tiles. Using the traditional view hierarchies to draw the board you'll only be able to animate a "tile" inside the bounds of the parent hierarchy. If you wanted to drop the items from the top, this would mean your parent hierarchy has to match your window size completely. Doing this will cause the board to be off-center obviously. So a custom ViewGroup is the answer. You layout the child views manually by calculating their x/y coordinates and their width and height.

A nice tutoral on custom ViewGroups: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-custom-layout-in-android-by-extending-viewgroup-class. This unfortunately is a more advanced topic in android dev. I highly recommend you start simple, use animations where possible, and once you have a working result start adding eye candy.

If you try to implement every fancy animation you'll most likely never actually finish your project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into it now and see what I can do. This is my first time working with android, but I have a good grasp in general programming. It might be enough.